# How do I post a http request in c# using FormUrlEncodedContent

Tags: c#, http

I would like to post a http request in order to login to a website using HttpClient and FormUrlEncodedContent. I can track how the response is supposed to look on my chrome browser, but when i recreate the post request made by my browser, I don't get the anticipated response. The website I'm trying to log into is https://www.lectio.dk/lectio/31/login.aspx.

I guess I'm in doubt as to what I should supply the FormUrlEncodedContent with (using the network tab in chrome I can see request headers and form data, but how do I select what I should supply?). Currently my code looks like this.

```
CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.CookieContainer = container;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            Console.WriteLine(client.DefaultRequestHeaders + "\n" + "--------------------------");

            Dictionary<string, string> vals = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"user-agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"},
                {"accept-language","en-GB,en-AS;q=0.9,en-DK;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,da-DK;q=0.6,da;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.4"},
                {"accept-encoding","gzip, deflate, br"},
                {"accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3"},
                {"m$Content$username2","username"},
                {"m$Content$passwordHidden","password"},
                {"__EVENTTARGET","m$Content$submitbtn2"},

            };
            FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(vals);
            var response = client.PostAsync("https://www.lectio.dk/lectio/31/login.aspx", content);
            var responseString = response.Result;
            Console.WriteLine(responseString);
            handler.Dispose();
            client.Dispose();
```

The idea is to be logged into the website(I guess my Cookiecontainer will take care of that?) so that I can scrape som data.

Comment: It seems unlikely that `FormUrlEncodedContent` would take _header values_ as its constructor. It seems likely it would take _form data_.

Comment: Ok, do I have to supply the header values at all or does the HttpClient take care of that?

Comment: It depends on the website. In theory it should (it passes its own User-Agent value), but if the developer of the site you're using has done something special to prevent non-browsers accessing it, then you might have to send some headers that it requires.